# How to optimize max function when paired with greater than comparison

Tags: python, optimization, max, generator

In the code below, `user_func` finds the max of values from a slow generator (`slow_func`), and returns true if the max is greater than 5. (In this example, the function should always return True)

`timeit` returns just over 10 seconds, meaning the full generator is exhausted. However, by the 6th value from the generator, the greater than comparison would be guaranteed to return True. Is there any builtin (or package) that I could use to quicken this comparison?

I think the complicating factor here is the fact that there is a second comparison in the `if` statement (currently represented by `3 > 2`)

```py
import random
from time import sleep
import timeit

def slow_func():
    i=1
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        yield i
        i+=1
        if i>10:
            return


def user_func():
    if (3 > 2) and max(slow_func())>5: # (3 > 2) is example of second comparison 
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(timeit.timeit('user_func()',"from __main__ import slow_func, user_func",number=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire generator is exhausted because when you do the following:

```
if max(slow_func())>5:
```

`max` first iterates over the entire generator to find the highest value, then the result is evaluated by your condition. If you want to return whether any value is greater than 5 as soon as possible, then you have to iterate yourself instead of looking for the highest value first. For example:

```
def user_func():
    for value in slow_func():
        if value > 5:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the code in my question to clarify that there is another comparison in the `if` statement. Any thought on how to incorporate that?

Comment: Where are 3 and 2 coming from? Are they already known values?

Comment: The 2 is a constant, the three is calculated upon arrival to the if statement.

Comment: I think I got it to work with `if (3 > 2) and any(x>5 for x in slow_func()):`

Comment: Yes, that would works as you intend it to. That said, if the goal of your condition is to only `return True` or `else False`, then you should not use an `if` and simply return your expression directly: `return (3 > 2) and...`. It is actually slightly faster, because Python do not have to assign the result to the local frame before exiting the call, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am not just returning True/False. Just cut everything down to a minimal example.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by replacing the max function with a comparison within a generator expression within `any`. Like so:

`if (3 > 2) and any(x>5 for x in slow_func()):`

This is because `any` will take a generator and return True as soon as a matching value is found. The generator inside `any` returns True or False for each value returned from the slow generator.

I think this is the best option as it allows chaining with other conditionals, and allows for the use of any applicable comparison (See below).

`max(a)>x`:   `any(b>x for b in a)`

`max(a)>=x`:  `any(b>=x for b in a)`

`min(a)<x`:   `any(b<x for b in a)`

`min(a)<=x`:  `any(b<=x for b in a)`